# Quakus - Kafka Smallrye | How to change client.id of the underlaying producer used when failure-strategy is dead-letter-queue

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I've setup a kafka consumer using smallrye kafka.
For particular reasons, I need to have control over the client.id of every producer on my code.

### So, how can i change the client.id of the producer used when a nack() is sent from my code?

My current incoming setup is:

```
@Incoming("shifts")
@Retry(delay = 10, maxRetries = 5)
public CompletionStage<Void> consume(KafkaRecord<K, V> record) {
  // for now, we log
  log.info("clShift message received: with key {} and value {} ", record.getKey(),record.getPayload());
  return record.nack(new Exception("this should do to dl"));
}
```

part of application.properties:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.shifts.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.shifts.topic=<topic_name>
mp.messaging.incoming.shifts.failure-strategy=dead-letter-queue
mp.messaging.incoming.shifts.kafka-configuration=default-kafka-broker
mp.messaging.incoming.shifts.auto.offset.reset=latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a requirement was not part of smallrye-reactive-messaging implementation.
It was added on version 4.0.0 on [commit](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/commit/ba1d4fada286cd8fe18db66667ea7d3f8f55a079)